# PHP display a value from a selected array index

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm using this JSON in the project: http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=us_bestitjobcities2015&format=json

As an Array it looks like this:

```
array(28) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["yr"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
    ["nm"]=>
    string(7) "Seattle"
    ["cd"]=>
    string(2) "WA"
    ["cst"]=>
    float(107)
    ["sal1"]=>
    int(107540)
    ["sal2"]=>
    int(79945)
    ["sal3"]=>
    int(72639)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["yr"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
    ["nm"]=>
    string(8) "San Jose"
    ["cd"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["cst"]=>
    float(122)
    ["sal1"]=>
    int(107121)
    ["sal2"]=>
    int(73367)
    ["sal3"]=>
    int(84530)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(7) {
    ["yr"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
    ["nm"]=>
    string(7) "Raleigh"
    ["cd"]=>
    string(2) "NC"
    ["cst"]=>
    float(95.2)
    ["sal1"]=>
    int(102950)
    ["sal2"]=>
    int(87131)
    ["sal3"]=>
    int(71758)
  }
}
```

What I've created is a page with a drop-down menu that is populated with data from certain fields in a JSON document found on the web. What I want to do is make it so that when you select one of the values from the drop-down menu, the page will display one of its "associated" values (values that are in the same index if I understand this right).

The drop-down menu is populated with the data from the "nm" fields.

So for example, if you select "Seattle" from the drop-down menu I want the page to display (by echo or something similar) the "sal1" value associated with that field. The "sal1" field associated with "Seattle" has a value of "107540". I do not want to display the other "sal1" values (such as the one associated with San Jose, which is value "107121".

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=us_bestitjobcities2015&format=json';

$jsonData = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);

//var_dump($jsonArray);
//echo gettype($jsonArray);

echo 
'<form action="index.php" method="get" name=phpform">
<select name="state">';
foreach($jsonArray as $data){
  echo '<option value="' . $data . '">' . $data['nm'] . '</option>';
  }

echo
'</select> 
<input type="submit" value="Velg" name="submitphp"></input>
</form>';
?>

<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vareliste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php   
    if(isset($_POST['submitphp'])) {
        foreach($jsonArray as $nr => $nr_value) {
            if($nr_value==$_GET['state']) echo $nr['sal1'];
        }
    }
    else echo "NA";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: just process them form like you normally do, since you explicitly used `GET`, just access the form when submitted as `$_GET['state']`

Comment: just use index `sal1` on the `value` attribute, `echo '<option value="' . $data['sal1'] . '">'` like so, then process the form

Comment: In `<form action="index.php" method="get" name=phpform">` a double quotation mark is missing: `<form action="index.php" method="get" name="phpform">`

Comment: @Ghost Thank you for the reply. I tried following what you said but I can't manage to make it work. The final echo gives me all the value of all the "sal1" indexes, while I only want to get the one under the same "key" as what I've selected from the drop-down (as in if I select Seattle I want "sal1" to be "107540"). Could you provide a full example so I could understand it easier?

Comment: no need with `foreach`, just remove it and just use `$_GET['state']` inside the `isset` block to get the selected value